# Siege error when running facebook-mediawiki workload

Tags: mediawiki, hhvm, siege

I was trying to run the facebook-mediawiki workload https://github.com/facebookarchive/oss-performance. Siege runs when i use --php. But gives the below error if i try to run the workload with --hhvm flag.

```
** SIEGE 4.0.3rc3
** Preparing 200 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
siege aborted due to excessive socket failure; you
can change the failure threshold in $HOME/.siegerc

Transactions:                  0 hits
Availability:               0.00 %
Elapsed time:               4.14 secs
Data transferred:           0.29 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:           0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.07 MB/sec
Concurrency:              190.71
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:            1223
Longest transaction:            1.26
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

`oss-performance`, as indicated by being in the "facebookarchive" github organisation, is no longer maintained or supported. In particular, HHVM itself no longer supports running PHP code such as Mediawiki (or, really, *any* of the various frameworks which `oss-performance` was built to test back in the day) -- HHVM is exclusively a runtime for the Hack language. The last version of HHVM which supported PHP was released in 2018, and that release became unsupported at the end of 2019.

More information on HHVM's departure from PHP is on [the HHVM blog](https://hhvm.com/blog/); taking a look at [this post](https://hhvm.com/blog/2018/09/12/end-of-php-support-future-of-hack.html) might be especially interesting.